# how to debug npm packet written by c++

Tags: c++, node.js, debugging, netbeans, packets

i wrote a node.js packet.When node load it，how to use gdb debug it.
i usually use netbeans to debug C++. netbeans support c++ and node.js.But do not know how to debug such node.js packets written by C++.

Comment: nodejs packets are just regular dlls, debugging them is no different from debugging regular dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to debug an [Addon](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) Node.js (written in c++), this is not a module even if you can load it as a node-module.

Unfortunately you cannot debug easily because there are 3 levels of code, the c++ code source, the v8(NaN) source which is a sugar above node & the node.js call of this add-on

So you will not find an IDE to fully trace the road from node to c++ source code :s

Comment: if IDE cannot debug Addon,how to use GDB to debug it?